# Let other containers access mongo official docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have several docker containers , one of them is Mongodb official image,

Here's part of  my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo01
#    command: ["mongod", "-f", "/etc/mongo/mongod.conf"]
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongodata:/data/db
#      - ./config/mongo:/etc/mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

I could access to mongo service from the host ( my system) but according to the  mongo new security policy  there is config for limit access to mongo just form `127.0.0.1`,I know it , it's

```
# network interfaces

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

if I could push the mongo image read my custom config I could resolve the problem, but I tried to

to mount  a custom config file `- ./config/mongo:/etc/mongo` and then run mongod with   `command: ["mongod", "-f", "/etc/mongo/mongod.conf"]`  but didn't  work.

it seems mongod starting in container as process 1 and try to run it with custom command not works,  even when I tried to shutdown the mongod in  container  with `mongod --shutdown` it shutdown the whole container.( I wanted to stop the mongod and then rerun it with `mongod --bind_ip_all` )

So the problem is how we can change the mongo image config file ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mongo [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) already has an ENTRYPOINT set and it basically is `mongod`, so in your command (CMD) you can add extra arguments to mongod

simple docker run

```
docker run -d mongo --bind_ip_all
```

or with compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    command: ["--bind_ip_all"]
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Answer (score 0):

The entrypoint for the official mongo image already [contains a step to add `--bind_ip_all`](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/21869963911a74ccc13697c3ad50cdc23cc79b15/4.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L332) as long as you don't explicitly bind a specific IP:

```
# MongoDB 3.6+ defaults to localhost-only binding
haveBindIp=
if _mongod_hack_have_arg --bind_ip "$@" || _mongod_hack_have_arg --bind_ip_all "$@"; then
    haveBindIp=1
elif _parse_config "$@" && jq --exit-status '.net.bindIp // .net.bindIpAll' "$jsonConfigFile" > /dev/null; then
    haveBindIp=1
fi
if [ -z "$haveBindIp" ]; then
    # so if no "--bind_ip" is specified, let's add "--bind_ip_all"
    set -- "$@" --bind_ip_all
fi
```

Comment: Yup, I saw it ,  How I can pass it to entrypoint? by command ?

Comment: @zhilevan You can pass those args as the command, and they will become parameters to the entrypoint. But you're overriding the default setting with the default, so I'm not sure what your goal is there.